# Proof of an inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality, tangent-line-method

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{\sqrt{a+b+c}+\sqrt{a}}{b+c} + \frac{\sqrt{a+b+c}+\sqrt{b}}{c+a} + \frac{\sqrt{a+b+c}+\sqrt{c}}{a+b} \geq \frac{9+3\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{a+b+c}}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Note $$b+c = (a+b+c)-a = (\sqrt{a+b+c}-\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{a+b+c}+\sqrt a)$$

Comment: To be humble, @MorganO, I tried several things - but finally none of them seemed to be on a correct direction. The last one I tried is multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{a+b+c}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the inequality is homogeneous, we can set $a+b+c = 1$, say.  Then we have to show the cyclic sum:
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1+\sqrt{a}}{1-a} = \sum_{cyc} \frac1{1- \sqrt a} \ge \frac{9+3\sqrt3}2$$

To show this, it is sufficient to show that 
$$f(x) = \frac1{1-\sqrt x} - \frac{3+\sqrt 3}2 - k(\tfrac13-x) \ge 0$$
for some $k \in \mathbb R$ and $x \in (0, 1)$, as the inequality is equivalent to $f(a)+f(b)+f(c) \ge 0$.

We find that $k = \frac34(3+2\sqrt 3)$ works, as then 
$$f(x) = \frac{(3 + 2 \sqrt3) \left(\sqrt3 - 3 \sqrt x \right)^2 (-3 + 2 \sqrt3 + 3 \sqrt x)}{36(1 - \sqrt x)} \ge 0, \quad \forall x \in (0, 1)$$

Comment: Had to change my answer as $t \mapsto \dfrac1{1-\sqrt t}$ is not convex close to $0$, so Jensen cannot be directly applied.

Comment: Perhaps easier would be Cauchy-Schwarz: with $$3 = (a+b+c)(1+1+1) \ge \left(\sum_{cyc} \sqrt a\right)^2 \implies \sum_{cyc} (1-\sqrt a) \le \frac6{3+\sqrt3}$$ and $$  \left( \sum_{cyc} \frac1{1- \sqrt a} \right) \left(\sum_{cyc} (1-\sqrt a) \right) \ge 9$$

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b+c+\sqrt{a(a+b+c)}}{b+c}\geq\frac{9+3\sqrt3}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a(a+b+c)}}{b+c}\geq\frac{3+3\sqrt3}{2}.$$
But by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab+ac}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(ab+ac+bc)}\geq\frac{3}{2}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{b+c}\geq\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{a+b+c}}.$$
Now, by Holder
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{b+c}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}a^2(b+c)^2\geq(a+b+c)^3.$$
Id est, it remains to prove that
$$4(a+b+c)^4\geq27\sum_{cyc}a^2(b+c)^2,$$
which is true by AM-GM:
$$27\sum_{cyc}a^2(b+c)^2=108\sum_{cyc}a\left(a\left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2\right)\leq$$
$$\leq108\sum_{cyc}a\left(\frac{a+\frac{b+c}{2}+\frac{b+c}{2}}{3}\right)^3=4\sum_{cyc}a(a+b+c)^3=4(a+b+c)^4.$$
Done!